# Razorpay object initialisation returning null in xamarin ios

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, razorpay

In my Xamarin ios project integrated razor payment by creating binding project and added the native reference by downloading razorpay framework from https://razorpay.com/docs/payments/payment-gateway/ios-integration/standard/

below razorpay object initialisation method returns null.

```
razorPay = Razorpay.InitWithKey("mykey", paymentDelegate);
```

using the same live key i'm able complete the payment successfully in android but for iOS it is failing.

[image]

Razorpay native reference property (downloaded from [link](https://razorpay.com/docs/payments/payment-gateway/ios-integration/standard/))

[image]

Imported below mentioned framework as a native reference
[image]

Reproduced the issue in the code downloaded from [here](https://github.com/InnovativeTechies/RazorPayXamariniOSBinding)

Uploaded the sample project with issue [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FMW6y97VZCLueeoHl2dmqu7BgmwGr1fj/view?usp=sharing)

Can anyone suggest me the solution
Thanks

Comment: Try to switch to RazorpayCheckout from Razorpay.

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT there is no defined symbol like  RazorpayCheckout

Comment: According to https://razorpay.com/docs/payments/payment-gateway/ios-integration/standard/build-integration/#12-initialize-razorpay-ios-standard-sdk For Swift version 5.1+, you need to ensure that you declare var razorpay: RazorpayCheckout. And For versions lower than 5.1, use var razorpay: Razorpay.

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT thanks for the input. Now i need to update my ApiDefinition.cs class(https://github.com/InnovativeTechies/RazorPayXamariniOSBinding/blob/master/RazorPayiOSBinding/ApiDefinition.cs) to include this new class and method any suggestion on how i can do that.   followed the steps mentioned here https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-xamarin-ios-binding-for-razorpay-payment-gateway/ still i didnt get the apidefenetion.cs

Comment: Here is a walkthrough about binding swift library https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-swift/walkthrough

Comment: Changed to RazorpayCheckout .InitWithKey("mykey", paymentDelegate); and updated the ApiDefinition.cs class still i'm getting same issue

Comment: @Suchith did you find any solution for this? I updated the ApiDefinition as per the latest SDK 1.3.4, and built the DLL with RazorpayCheckout, still getting null.

Comment: @ArjunKR didn't get any solution, razorpay is not supporting Xamarin/Maui. Alternate could be using razorpay webview approach. https://www.appliedcodelog.com/2023/03/payment-gateway-integration-in-net-maui.html

Comment: @Suchith thanks will try this approach, I contacted the tech team of Razorpay, they have no plans to support MAUI as of now. Need to follow web approach.